# How to copy page structure SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout

I made a SharePoint page like this in the picture with only HTML and CSS.

[image]

Now I need to explain to colleagues

- How to create the same pages with different text. I have to create a page layout in SharePoint Designer or what?

I don't know if my tables will work correctly after making .aspx
Please help